# Building for prod don't take styleUrls from components

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ecmascript-6, sass

In my development everything is working ok, but when I build project for prod 
`ng build --prod app1-admin-app` angular CLI don't take my `.scss` file from my component, only the main style.scss.

when I build my core app, everything working like expect.... when I build any of my projects, I get this problem...

First I build app with `.css` style from scratch, but now I convert to `.sass`

I made everything like explained for change everything to `.scss` from [here](https://medium.com/@rageshchakkadath/migrate-your-existing-angular-6-application-from-css-to-scss-f555749d490e)

Here is my angular.json

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "app1-application-core": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {},
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/app1-application-core",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "aot": false,
            "assets": ["src/favicon.ico", "src/assets"],
            "styles": [
              "./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css",
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
              "node_modules/hammerjs/hammer.min.js"
            ]
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "6kb",
                  "maximumError": "10kb"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "app1-application-core:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "app1-application-core:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "app1-application-core:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
            "assets": ["src/favicon.ico", "src/assets"],
            "styles": [
              "./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css",
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "tsconfig.app.json",
              "tsconfig.spec.json",
              "e2e/tsconfig.json"
            ],
            "exclude": ["**/node_modules/**"]
          }
        },
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "app1-application-core:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "app1-application-core:serve:production"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "app1-admin-app": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {},
      "root": "projects/app1-admin-app",
      "sourceRoot": "projects/app1-admin-app/src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/app1-admin-app",
            "index": "projects/app1-admin-app/src/index.html",
            "main": "projects/app1-admin-app/src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "projects/app1-admin-app/src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "projects/app1-admin-app/tsconfig.app.json",
            "aot": false,
            "assets": [
              "projects/app1-admin-app/src/favicon.ico",
              "projects/app1-admin-app/src/assets",
              "projects/app1-admin-app/src/manifest.webmanifest"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css",
              "projects/app1-admin-app/src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": ["node_modules/hammerjs/hammer.min.js"]
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "projects/app1-admin-app/src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "projects/app1-admin-app/src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "6kb",
                  "maximumError": "10kb"
                }
              ],
              "serviceWorker": true
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "app1-admin-app:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "app1-admin-app:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "app1-admin-app:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "projects/app1-admin-app/src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "projects/app1-admin-app/src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "projects/app1-admin-app/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "projects/app1-admin-app/karma.conf.js",
            "assets": [
              "projects/app1-admin-app/src/favicon.ico",
              "projects/app1-admin-app/src/assets",
              "projects/app1-admin-app/src/manifest.webmanifest"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css",
              "projects/app1-admin-app/src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "projects/app1-admin-app/tsconfig.app.json",
              "projects/app1-admin-app/tsconfig.spec.json",
              "projects/app1-admin-app/e2e/tsconfig.json"
            ],
            "exclude": ["**/node_modules/**"]
          }
        },
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "projects/app1-admin-app/e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "app1-admin-app:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "app1-admin-app:serve:production"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
  "defaultProject": "app1-application-core",
  "cli": {
    "defaultCollection": "@ngrx/schematics"
  },
  "schematics": {
    "@schematics/angular:component": {
      "styleext": "scss"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your css files should have `.scss` extension and you should include them in your components like so:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'workspace',
  templateUrl: './workspace.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./workspace.component.scss']
})
```

Comment: in every component I have included files like in your example... I generate component with Angular CLI, and get everything included on this way

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your schematics section

```
"projects": {
    "app1-application-core": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {
                    "@schematics/angular:component": {
                        "style": "scss"
                    }
                },
```

And remove the schematics section at the end of angular.json there should be 1 schematics section in angular.json

Make sure to run ng serve again after you modify your angular.json

Comment: If u take a look at the end of my `angular.json` you will see i have ´"schematics": {
    "@schematics/angular:component": {
      "styleext": "scss"
    }
  }´ but it is in root in JSON... do I need to change something?

Comment: Check my answer again @Arter.

Comment: Before I try, do I need to change my `syleext` to `style` like in your example?

Comment: @Arter yes it must be the same

Comment: I  change everything as you say, but the same problem is here

Comment: Yes, I build again app and run with npx serve

Comment: Nope ng serve not npx serve

Comment: when I run ng serve in dev mode, everything is working, I need to run from my dist folder builded app...  with ng serve I can not run builded app or?

Comment: To build your code in production run `ng build --prod` every css will be combine into 1 css file in dist folder

Comment: I know, and that is my problem+... in my `styles.96c608ebae39b554115b.css` in dist folder i only have css from angular-material, and from root styles.scss.... ng build --prod didn't take my .scss from my components

Comment: when I build my core app, everything working like expect.... when I build any of my projects, I get this problem like in my question... Mabey this help?